# Adding a row with Sum and mean of the columns

Tags: r

I'm having a dataframe as like below.

```
    `> am_me
      Group.1         Group.2 x.x       x.y
    2      AM  clearterminate   3  21.00000
    3      AM display.cryptic  86  30.12791
    4      AM           price  71 898.00000`
```

I would like to get result as like below.

```
    `> am_me_t
               Group.2 x.x              x.y
    2   clearterminate   3               21
    3  display.cryptic  86 30.1279069767442
    4            price  71              898
    41            AM 160 316.375968992248`
```

I have taken out the first column and got the result like below

```
    `> am_res
              Group.2 x.x       x.y
    2  clearterminate   3  21.00000
    3 display.cryptic  86  30.12791
    4           price  71 898.00000`
```

When I try rbind to Add "AM" to new row, as like below, I'm getting a warning message and getting NA.

```
     `> am_me_t <- rbind(am_res, c("AM", colSums(am_res[2]), colMeans(am_res[3])))
    Warning message:
    invalid factor level, NAs generated in: "[<-.factor"(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "AM")

               Group.2 x.x              x.y
    2   clearterminate   3               21
    3  display.cryptic  86 30.1279069767442
    4            price  71              898
    41            <NA> 160 316.375968992248`
```

For your information, Output of edit(am_me)

```
    `> edit(am_me)
    structure(list(Group.1 = structure(as.integer(c(2, 2, 2)), .Label = c("1Y",
    "AM", "BE", "CM", "CO", "LX", "SN", "US", "VK", "VS"), class = "factor"),
        Group.2 = structure(as.integer(c(2, 5, 9)), .Label = c("bestbuy",
        "clearterminate", "currency.display", "display", "display.cryptic",
        "fqa", "mileage.display", "ping", "price", "reissue", "reissuedisplay",
        "shortaccess.followon"), class = "factor"), x.x = as.integer(c(3,
        86, 71)), x.y = c(21, 30.1279069767442, 898)), .Names = c("Group.1",
    "Group.2", "x.x", "x.y"), row.names = c("2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")`
```

Also

```
    `> edit(me)
    structure(list(Group.1 = structure(as.integer(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8,
    8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), .Label = c("1Y", "AM",
    "BE", "CM", "CO", "LX", "SN", "US", "VK", "VS"), class = "factor"),
        Group.2 = structure(as.integer(c(8, 2, 5, 9, 10, 1, 2, 5,
        9, 1, 2, 5, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5,
        9, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10)), .Label = c("bestbuy", "clearterminate",
        "currency.display", "display", "display.cryptic", "fqa",
        "mileage.display", "ping", "price", "reissue", "reissuedisplay",
        "shortaccess.followon"), class = "factor"), x.x = as.integer(c(1,
        3, 86, 71, 1, 2, 5, 1, 52, 10, 7, 27, 15, 5, 267, 14, 4,
        1, 256, 1, 1, 80, 1, 78, 2, 10, 23, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 11,
        1, 1)), x.y = c(5, 21, 30.1279069767442, 898, 12280, 800,
        56.4, 104, 490.442307692308, 1759.1, 18.1428571428571, 1244.81481481481,
        518.533333333333, 3033.2, 18.5468164794007, 20, 3788.5, 23,
        2053.49609375, 3863, 6376, 17.825, 240, 1752.21794871795,
        1114.5, 34, 1369.60869565217, 1062.16666666667, 23, 245,
        5681.5, 11.3333333333333, 13.3333333333333, 1273.81818181818,
        2076, 5724)), .Names = c("Group.1", "Group.2", "x.x", "x.y"
    ), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
    "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
    "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31",
    "32", "33", "34", "35", "36"), class = "data.frame")

       Group.1              Group.2 x.x         x.y
    1       1Y                 ping   1     5.00000
    2       AM       clearterminate   3    21.00000
    3       AM      display.cryptic  86    30.12791
    4       AM                price  71   898.00000
    5       BE              reissue   1 12280.00000
    6       CM              bestbuy   2   800.00000
    7       CM       clearterminate   5    56.40000
    8       CM      display.cryptic   1   104.00000
    9       CM                price  52   490.44231
    10      CO              bestbuy  10  1759.10000
    11      CO       clearterminate   7    18.14286
    12      CO      display.cryptic  27  1244.81481
    13      CO                price  15   518.53333
    14      LX              bestbuy   5  3033.20000
    15      LX       clearterminate 267    18.54682
    16      LX     currency.display  14    20.00000
    17      LX              display   4  3788.50000
    18      LX      mileage.display   1    23.00000
    19      LX                price 256  2053.49609
    20      LX       reissuedisplay   1  3863.00000
    21      LX shortaccess.followon   1  6376.00000
    22      SN       clearterminate  80    17.82500
    23      SN              display   1   240.00000
    24      SN                  fqa  78  1752.21795
    25      US              bestbuy   2  1114.50000
    26      US       clearterminate  10    34.00000
    27      US      display.cryptic  23  1369.60870
    28      US                price   6  1062.16667
    29      VK       clearterminate   1    23.00000
    30      VK      display.cryptic   2   245.00000
    31      VS              bestbuy   4  5681.50000
    32      VS       clearterminate   3    11.33333
    33      VS     currency.display   3    13.33333
    34      VS      display.cryptic  11  1273.81818
    35      VS                price   1  2076.00000
    36      VS              reissue   1  5724.00000`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the Group.2 column is factor, and that limits the possible values. You can transform it to character with `am_me$Group.2 <- as.character(am_me$Group.2)`, after that the AM value will be added without errors.

Note that you can also use `sum()` and `mean()` for single column operations.

Comment: It also turns out that storing character strings as factors does not save memory, from ?factor: `In earlier versions of R, storing character data as a factor was more space efficient if there is even a small proportion of repeats. Since R 2.6.0 identical character strings share storage, so the difference is now small in most cases. (Integer values are stored in 4 bytes whereas each reference to a character string needs a pointer of 4 or 8 bytes.) 

`

Comment: That will only work if 'AM' is also of class "character". If it's also of class "factor", I'm suspicious the same error will result. And 'AM' is very likely the case since Meshach does not seem to understand factors and the fact that read.* functions all create factors by default.